# how to minimize hdd spinups?

Tags: hard-disk, sata, hdparm

I have a mdadm RAID 1 of two Toshiba MG09 18Ts in my pc but I don't need to access them very often, maybe 1-2 times a week.
I'm booting the pc once per day which also spins up the hdds.
When using a systemd service to put the drives to sleep right after boot they sleep until they are accessed, or, and thats one part that annoys me, when I'm shutting down. Is there a way to prevent spinning up on shutdown?

I have also read about a SATA feature called "power up in standby" / PUIS to not spin up the drives on boot but from the hdparm -s description I'm unsure whether I could actually use this. Using the latest kernel the OS should support this feature. But I couldn't find any info on whether the drives or my mainboard (Crosshair VI Hero) support it. Is there a way to safely check if this feature is supported?

Comment: SATA supports hotplug so you could use a physical power switch for those HDDs. Otherwise not sure if `unbind`ing the drive or entire controller would work (if you're really extra sure all changes are synced to the drives).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, however I would prefer a software solution if somehow possible. Is there a way to unbind the drives in a way that they wouldnt be recognized by the OS, like when shutting down, but also be still mountable if needed?

Comment: The spinup on shutdown ist most probably caused by umounting the filesystem (ark it as clean), stopping the mdraid (also marking as cleanly unassembled) or a combination of them. Only way to get around is, manually assemble raid&mount, and if done using it umount and disassemble raid. Not the smoothest solution though.